# How to extract post parameters from iPhone client in wcf rest service?

Tags: iphone, json, wcf, rest, http-post

I have a iPhone application consuming wcf RESTful service. Everything works fine if i use `GET` method. But when I use post method & pass parameters in web service URL, `NSURL` is nil as i have some special characters in post parametres. So I used `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` to construct url. But now at server side url is not recognized and it's not been able to map to proper method in web service template.

1. Is there any solution to this?
2. If i pass post parameters as HTTPBody & not in `NSURL` itself then how
   to handle it at server side in ASP.net. (Note it is wcf restful web-service).
3. Is there any other way to using `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`

Comment: why you need special characters in URL? Could you please give us an example?